# services are started before their filesystems had been mounted

Tags: systemd, mount, lvm, usb-drive

Dear systemd experts,

I have Cubietruck A20 system with Armbian kernel 4.19.62 and the rest of packages taken from Debian 10 Buster armhf, systemd is 241-7~deb10u2.

To save my boot microSD card from wearing down, I created a LVM2 volume group on USB-attached HDD (WD5000BMVW, Western Digital Elements / My Passport (USB)), and a number of ext4 filesystems on LVs in this VG, to store /var/lib , /var/log , some of /var/spool/* , /var/cache , and so on .

I properly recorded all these filesystems in /etc/fstab and they are mounted on system boot.

But as a result, some services have become dependent on these filesystems having been mounted before they start. In part, bind9 (named) and squid (squid3). And after next reboot I noticed that these services are started earlier than they have these filesystems mounted & accessible.

So I asked some systemd experts, and they said, "run 'systemctl edit' and add .mount dependencies on these services". And I added override files for bind9 and squid with content like that :

```
# /etc/systemd/system/squid.service.d/override.conf
[Unit]
Requires=var-log.mount var-spool-squid3.mount
After=var-log.mount var-spool-squid3.mount
```

and

```
# /etc/systemd/system/bind9.service.d/override.conf
[Unit]
Requires=var-lib.mount var-cache.mount
After=var-lib.mount var-cache.mount
```

and this did not help, else I would not be asking my question.
You can be sure that I took these .mount names from the printout of 'systemctl list-units', and tried Requires and After both alone and together

In 'journalctl -b' I see very clearly that bind9 and squid .services are started very early and failing; and only some seconds later, usb block device (sda) is discovered, lvm pvscan is run, and found LVs are activated and mounted. So I assume these .mount units simply do not exist when bind9&squid .service start is attempted.

So my question is, how to *properly* specify this kind of dependencies when some of mandatory boot-time filesystems are discovered some seconds later than unit files are read from the root FS and dependency-ordered by systemd ?

Thanks in advance for your useful responses.

Comment: well, Debian maintainers told me this was caused by resolvconf init script triggering all update hooks under /etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d/ without regarding systemd dependencies.see https://bugs.debian.org/945002 and https://bugs.debian.org/960594 for details